# Reading of binary file

Tags: c++, fstream

I got segmentation problem while reading binary file.

File size is 16859136 bytes, containing double values, but in fact I can read about 4214784 bytes (4 times less).

I use the following c++ code.

```
const int size = 6*28*28*28*4*4; // 16859136(bytes) = size * 8(bytes)  
double data[size];

ifstream in;
in.open("/path/to/file", std::fstream::binary);
if (in.is_open()) { cout << "File is open!\n"; }

in.read((char *) &data, sizeof(data));
cout << in.gcount() << " bytes read\n";

in.close();
```

Output:

Segmentation fault

PS: Maybe there is some kind of syntax error...

Comment: If `data` is within function scope, you're almost certainly overflowing your stack. That array is too darn big.

Comment: Variably sized arrays are not part of C++. They probably work because something like that does exist in C and some C++ compilers port C features to C++. Use `std::vector<double>` instead and that part should be fine.

Comment: @DietmarKühl This isn’t a variable-sized array, `size` is a constant expression. But yes, this should definitely be a `std::vector`.

Comment: Fair enough. It is still too big for a typical stack and using `std::vector<double>` will fix the underlying problem.

Comment: If you have a `segmentation error`, that means the program started running and crushed. Which means it compiled correctly, which means no syntax error. In addition, when you ask for help with a program crash, you should provide the line that caused it to crash (the segmentation fault).

Answer (score 2):

The following lines allocate a space too large on your stack:

```
const int size = 6*28*28*28*4*4; // 16859136(bytes) = size * 8(bytes)  
double data[size];
```

consider instead a heap allocation:

```
std::vector<double> data(6*28*28*28*4*4);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but the problem remains. Problem on in.read((char *) &data, sizeof(data));

Comment: I corrected this line, but it did not help. New code:   in.read((char *) &data, data.size() * sizeof(double));

Comment: Then you should also correct this line - now that it's a vector, you should `in.read((char*)data.data(), data.size() * sizeof(double));`